# Tomcat RMI issues when setting port

Tags: java, tomcat

Trying to set up a RMI on my tomcat 8 server at a webhosting firm. Getting some strange issues.

So first bit is the JAVAOPT setting, added the following to setenv.sh
rw-r--r-- 1 tentogive tentogive   2040 Sep 24 20:03 configtest.bat

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -server -Xms48m -Xmx256m\
                        -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true \
                        -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
                        -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=14648 \
                        -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
                        -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=XX.XXX.XX.XXX"
```

Tomcat comes up with these settings, but I can not connect to jmx.

JMX requires two ports (have opened them), in this case it is port 14648 and 23208, so added them to server.xml as a listener, as below:

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener" rmiRegistryPortPlatform="14648" rmiServerPortPlatform="23208" />
```

Then I get the following error in catalina.log

```
12-Oct-2014 08:57:43.764 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:
  2.6.32-531.17.1.lve1.2.60.el6.x86_64
12-Oct-2014 08:57:43.764 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:
  amd64
12-Oct-2014 08:57:43.764 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:
  1.8.0_05-b13
12-Oct-2014 08:57:43.765 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:
  Oracle Corporation
12-Oct-2014 08:57:43.766 SEVERE [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement Begin event
threw exception
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:116)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1184)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Sour
ce)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknow
n Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.n
ext(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown So
urce)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1457)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:613)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

12-Oct-2014 08:57:43.767 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Catalina.start using co
nf/server.xml: Error at (34, 67) : org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener
12-Oct-2014 08:57:43.767 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Cannot start server. Se
rver instance is not configured.
```

Comment: From [the documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/listeners.html#JMX_Remote_Lifecycle_Listener_-_org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener): _This listener requires catalina-jmx-remote.jar to be placed in $CATALINA_HOME/lib_. Is it? Also in the documentation _rmiRegistryPortPlatform: This replaces the use of the com.sun.management.jmxremote.port system property that should not be set when using this listener_. Have you _actually_ **read** the documentation?

Comment: Also, you want to use `CATALINA_OPTS` instead of `JAVA_OPTS` - otherwise you can't shutdown your tomcat with `shutdown.bat/shutdown.sh`.